# How to Get the URL from the Current Firefox Window via Windows' Command Line?

Tags: windows, firefox, command-line

I need to get the URL from the Current Firefox Window,
but without creating and installing an Add-on.

Is it possible to do it via Windows' Command Line?

By "Command Line" I mean the Command Prompt of Windows,
and not the Console pane inside Firefox..

So I can run:

```
firefox.exe -somecommand/parameters
```

and then get the `StdOut` with the String that is the Current URL

I need this for an outside application, that is not an Add-on..

Answer (score 0):

How are you attempting to access the url?

you can always type

```js
window.location.href
```

into the console?